# Is 'entrance ticket' used metaphorically?

Tags: expressions, metaphors

I want to say something about parenthood being constructed in our culture as the thing that allows one to enter adult society. Could I say parenthood is an entrance ticket to adult society? Would a native English speaker say that?

Comment: Your title doesn't really express your question.  You want to know if "entrance ticket" is good English and an appropriate metaphor, but that's not what the title is saying.  Since you ask, I think it's clumsy English.

Comment: What @itsbruce said. But rather than calling it "clumsy English" I'd say it's a strange sentiment in the first place. Far more likely would be something like *parenthood is a **sign that you have entered** adult society*.

Comment: 1. The primary sense of 'ticket' in AE is a ticket of admission, so 'entrance' is redundant. 2. What FumbleFingers says.

Comment: Just thinking...parenthood could be called an E-ticket to adulthood.  Now antiquated, of course, but the reference is to the most exhilerating ticket from the Disneyland/World ticket package.

Comment: @KristinaLopez: Not antiquated, it just has a different meaning now. (I use e-tickets every time I fly from my home airport.) That said, I like your parallel between the adventures of Disneyland and parenthood, so, one could say: "Parenthood is your _Disneyland gate pass_ into adulthood."

Comment: @J.R., Touche! The use of "e-" for everything electronic slipped right by me.  Good one!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a native speaker - but

> In our culture, parenthood is your ticket to adult society

sounds ok to me.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider

> Parenthood gives [entrée](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/entr%C3%A9e?q=entree) to adult society

Answer (score 0):

*Ticket* is used metaphorically, but in a slightly different sense. Have a look at [these examples](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/ask-teacher/59973-ticket-metaphorical-sense.html):

> Her husband was her *ticket* to wealth/power
>
> That song was his *ticket* to fame

In that sense, it means something analogue to Willy Wonka's [golden ticket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie_and_the_Chocolate_Factory). A lucky find that brings something positive/profitable.

From what I understand from your question, you mean *entrance* quite literally, *entering into adulthood* in this specific case. Right?

Answer (score 0):

What you have said doesn't sound silly to a native speaker, but I think something like

> Parenthood is a *gateway* to adult society

might sound better.

Comment: I like _doorway_ even better than _gateway_. I'd probably say it like this: _Parenthood is a doorway into adulthood._

Comment: @J.R. They seem to be roughly equivalent, so it's probably a matter of personal taste.

Comment: Alan: _gateway_ often means the first of several successive steps – sometimes negatively, or in the wrong direction, as in _gateway drug._ For that reason, I think some might regard _gateway_ a bit differently than _doorway_. In this case, though, that subtle difference could work to the speaker's advantage, maybe even making the statement sound a bit more comical: first, it's buying diapers and strollers; minivans and PTA meetings are just around the corner! Ultimately, though, I agree with you – there's wiggle room on either side. I just wanted to offer an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to come up with a metaphor that suggests a transition into adulthood – something like a [coming-of-age](http://www.wordnik.com/words/coming%20of%20age) experience, only at the adult level.

You've proposed *ticket*. I don't mind *ticket*, although I think *entrance ticket* sounds awkward and redundant.  But *ticket* on its own works just fine:

> Parenthood is your ticket into adult society.

Besides *ticket*, you could also use *doorway* or *gateway* (as Alan proposed).  Other words that might work include:

- *on-ramp*
- *bridge*
- *first step*

All of these can be used metaphorically, for example:

> “Summer jobs provide young people a critical on-ramp to the road towards responsibility, community, work ethic, stability and economic self-sufficiency.” <sup>1</sup>
>
> “Natural gas is the bridge into a low carbon world.” <sup>2</sup>

---

<sub>S O U R C E S</sub>

<sup>1</sup> The Huffington Post: *Jon Bon Jovi: Going All in For All Youth*. Quote taken from [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/on-ramp).
<sup>2</sup> Trond Giske, as quoted in the *[Taipei Times](http://www.taipeitimes.com/News/editorials/archives/2012/06/10/2003534952/2)*.